# minimum and maximum value of a global variable with 2 thread

Tags: multithreading

I have a for loop like
`int c = 0 ; 
for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
     c++;`

where C is a global variable.
if I run this code with 2 thread what is the minimum and maximum final value of `C` if I don't lock the threads in the section of `c++` and how?

Comment: It is a good idea to define the type of `c` and its initial value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [minimum value of a counter accessed by two threads without synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040473/minimum-value-of-a-counter-accessed-by-two-threads-without-synchronization)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if you translate increment code to assembly it's pseudocode will be like:

```
1-mov ax,mem[c]
2-inc ax
3-mov mem[c],ax
```

if we have 2 thread consider this scenario:

```
thread 1: line 1
thread 2: line (1-2-3) for 99 times
thread 1: line (2-3)
thread 2: line 1
thread 1: line (1-2-3) for remaining 99 times
thread 2: line (2-3) for the last time
```

now the value of *c* is 2 so minimum is 2

Answer (score 1):

**My answer is minimum 1 and maximum 200.**

As Kibo mentioned, increment code looks like:
1-mov ax,mem[c]
2-inc ax
3-mov mem[c],ax

Now lets run an example with for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)

T1 line 1 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 2 |==> ax = 1; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 1 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 3 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 2 |==> ax = 1; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 1 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 3 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 2 |==> ax = 1; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 1 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 3 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 2 |==> ax = 1; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 1 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 3 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 2 |==> ax = 1; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 1 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T1 line 3 |==> ax = 0; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 2 |==> ax = 1; mem[c]=0;
T2 line 3 |==> ax = 1; mem[c]=1;

The same is applicable for i=200

Answer (score 0):

Minimum:
c+100
If Thread2 copies c before Thread1 overwrites.

Maximum:
c + 200
If both threads progress in sequence

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `c=0` initially

Max would be `200`

And that would happen if each thread executed `c++` after each other but in a single iteration.

Min would be `100`

That is because `c++` is basically:

```
temp = c + 1 //line1
c = temp //line2
```

Assume first thread does line1 and then then second thread does line`. The same value will be set.
So`c`will only increase by`1` in that iteration even 2 threads tried increasing it.

In Java, to make it thread-safe: declare `c` as `AtomicInteger` and do `c.addAndGet()` to increment it

Answer (score 0):

Minimum value will be c + 100.
Maximum value will be c + 200.

When threads run next to eachother they might take the same value of c at the same time before it was updated by the other thread. In this case both will update c to the same value.

If this happens at worst case scenario (the number of times you loop the function)
the value will be updated only that amount of times.

If this never happens (Your best case scenario), for instance the threads didn't run at the same, the value will be updated the amounts of times you want them to.

Comment: I was recently asked the same question in an interview, but the values were changed slightly.
`c=0;
for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    c++; // 5 threads are acting on this simultaneously`

I gave the answer as : Max:25 and Min:5 .
But the interviewer said the min value is 2. Can you explain where I went wrong?