# minimum value of a counter accessed by two threads without synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've been told in an interview that the minimum value for counter after running the following code is 2. How is that possible?

```
    class ThreadsConflict {
            private static int counter = 0;

            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
                    Thread t1 = new A();
                    Thread t2 = new A();
                    t1.start();
                    t2.start();

                    t1.join();
                    t2.join();

                    System.out.println(counter);
            }

            static class A extends Thread {
                    public void run() {
                            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                    counter++;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

I can understand why it will be 10 if they are interleaved and the ++ operator is conflicting but how is it possible that it will be under 10?

Answer (score 3):

That's because interleaving occurs between non atomic operations so `counter++` can be interrupted in the middle, sort of:

```
int tmp = counter;
/* threads gets interrupted here */
counter = tmp + 1;
```

This may lead to corner case situations as:

- thread A reads 0
- thread B reads 0 and writes 1
- thread B reads 1 and writes 2
- ...
- thread B reads 8 and writes 9
- thread A writes 1
- thread B reads 1
- thread A reads 1 and writes 2
- thread A reads 2 and writes 3
- ...
- thread A reads 9 and writes 10
- thread A finished
- thread B writes 2
- thread B finished

Mind that this is because `i` is used as a condition so exactly 10 iterations are done, if you were using directly `counter` then you'll be guaranteed to have at least 10.

Comment: I see how you've achieved `2` but why is it minimal? (Just interested)

Comment: Because there is no worse way (from threading perspective) that the threads will run.

Comment: I've run this many times with results from 10 to 20. It's going to depend on the number of threads in the system, which thread gets CPU and when. A can completely finish before B gets going. Although your scenario is possible it is highly unlikely.

Comment: @edharned, After five years of maintaining a huge, multi-threaded, enterprise application; I've learned that "highly unlikely" means that it will never occur in testing, but it _might_ bring down a customer's public-facing web portal.

Comment: @edharned: that's irrelevant, if you are not able to prove that something is not going to happen, how likely it could happen is just a trap that will trigger in the worst moment.

Comment: Why couldn't thread `A` read `0`, thread `B` does it's whole loop from `0` to `10` and then thread A writes `1`?

Comment: The interview question is a bad question. Everything that follows is irrelevant. As I said, it all depends on the environment.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Thread A also has to run 10 times, so in your case the final value would be 10.